# MySql dead lock in select and update query

Tags: c#, mysql, database

I have a table with composite primary key made up of 3 columns: key1, key2 and key3

I have another column called 'Order' which keeps track of order of the items in database. Everytime an item is added to the database, I have to make sure that the 'Order' column has the highest value (for the same group defined by key1, and key2). So for example:

```
key1 | key2 | key3 | order
--------------------------
1    | 2    | 10   | 0
1    | 2    | 11   | 10
1    | 2    | 12   | 20
1    | 2    | 13   | 30
```

Now if I have to add a new item (1, 2, 14) then the order must be greater than 30 so that the item is add the end of the list.
User can also reorder the items, which means I can modify the 'Order' column of (1, 2, 12) to have value of -10 and bring it on top of the list.

It is all well and fine until we add items to the table concurrently. I have to make sure that the 'Order' value is not duplicated for the items in the same group (items that have equal values for key1 and key2).

So, my SQL code for adding new item looks like this:

```
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (1, 2, 14, null);

UPDATE table_name SET `Order`=
(
    SELECT * FROM (SELECT COALESCE((SELECT MAX(`Order)
        FROM table_name
        WHERE `key1`=1 AND `key2`=2), 0)+10) a
) where `key1`=1 AND `key2`=2 AND `key3`=14;
COMMIT;
```

The above transaction is run using C# code. Between the insert and update, the C# code check whether or not the `Order` column needs to be calculated. For example for combination of key1=1 and key2=2, we might need to calculate the Order but not for combination key=1 and key2=3 and leave it null. That is the reason why the insert sql doesn't calculate Order column and leaves it as null.

Now the problem is, it works quiet well until I try adding lot of records concurrently. I have a program that sends 20 items concurrently and not all of them are added to the database successfully because it deadlocks at the update statement.

Can anyone suggest me some ways to prevent the deadlock, or maybe a better design.

Thanks

**EDIT:**

Tried computing Order on insert but I get the deadlock on insert now. 
My insert basically looked like:

```
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (1, 2, 14, (SELECT * FROM (SELECT COALESCE((SELECT MAX(Order) FROM table_name WHERE key1=1 AND key2`=2), 0)+10) a));
```

**EDIT:**

So this is the log I get when I do: SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;

```
2016-08-19 09:38:08 15fc
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 2764458, ACTIVE 0 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 3, locked 3
LOCK WAIT 9 lock struct(s), heap size 2936, 6 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 1780, OS thread handle 0x5508, query id 85256 localhost ::1 root Sending data
UPDATE table_name SET `Order`=
                     (
                        SELECT * FROM (SELECT COALESCE((SELECT MAX(`Order`) 
                            FROM table_name
                            WHERE `key1`=164420 AND `key2`=2), 0)+4294967296) c
                     )
                     WHERE `key1`=164420 AND `key2`=2 AND `key3`=3368
*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 167 page no 1939 n bits 352 index `PRIMARY` of table `table_name` trx table locks 3 total table locks 2  trx id 2764458 lock mode S waiting lock hold time 0 wait time before grant 0 
*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 2764459, ACTIVE 0 sec fetching rows
mysql tables in use 3, locked 3
11 lock struct(s), heap size 2936, 23 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 1782, OS thread handle 0x15fc, query id 85259 localhost ::1 root Sending data
UPDATE table_name SET `Order`=
                     (
                        SELECT * FROM (SELECT COALESCE((SELECT MAX(`Order`) 
                            FROM table_name
                            WHERE `key1`=164420 AND `key2`=2), 0)+4294967296) c
                     )
                     WHERE `key1`=164420 AND `key2`=2 AND `key3`=3338
*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 167 page no 1939 n bits 352 index `PRIMARY` of table `table_name` trx table locks 3 total table locks 2  trx id 2764459 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap lock hold time 0 wait time before grant 0 
*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 167 page no 1939 n bits 352 index `PRIMARY` of table `table_name` trx table locks 3 total table locks 2  trx id 2764459 lock mode S waiting lock hold time 0 wait time before grant 0 
*** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (1)
```

Comment: If your C# code knows before it starts what the key values are, can't it tell whether or not to calculate the `Order` column before you do the insert?

Comment: I have to insert whether the Order is calculated or not. This table is not just used for Order, it's used for association of different objects as well.

Comment: Yes, but why can't you calculate Order at the time you insert?

Comment: Would doing that solve the deadlock issue? Not too sure it would but I can give it a try.

Comment: I think it's worth a try.

Comment: Just tried it but I get the deadlock on insert now. My insert basically looked like:
    INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (1, 2, 14, (SELECT * FROM (SELECT COALESCE((SELECT MAX(`Order)
        FROM table_name
        WHERE `key1`=1 AND `key2`=2), 0)+10) a));

Comment: You should [edit] your question instead of posting code in comments. (Oops, this is MySQL - removed stuff about SQL Trace)

Comment: Try making the `Order` column `AUTO_INCREMENT` rather than attempting to calculate it yourself. Any newly inserted rows will automatically receive the highest value for `Order`. You can still modify the `Order` values of existing rows when updating them, so users can still reorder things.

Comment: You seem to be performing atomic updates (some column needs to have a guaranteed unique value among a group of rows). Presumably, you are using some kind of locking and transaction isolation to make sure that these atomic updates work as expected. Deadlocks cannot be avoided if atomicity is enforced in a concurrent environment with stringent locking and transaction isolation (search Google for details). Therefore, you will be unable to get rid of the deadlocks completely. The only solution is to retry a few times (6-40 times depending on concurrent load) before giving up fully.

Comment: I need it get the highest value for Order based on key1 and key2 combination. So (1, 2) and (1, 3) both can have 1 in Order column. I can't use the highest value based on all the rows of that table.

Comment: Yeah, retry is the only solution I have thought of so far and it does work.

Comment: `AUTO_INCREMENT` would indeed give unique values for `Order` on insert, but you can subsequently change them to non-unique values during an update. But I guess you want uniformly distributed `Order` values among your groups. Something else to consider, then, is changing the isolation level of the transaction to ` SERIALIZABLE`. This will technically cause a performance hit, but it might not be noticeable. Test to confirm.

Comment: Tried the serializable isolation level but still got the deadlock. I have added the deadlock log in the original post.

Comment: Any transaction isolation level that results in locking will lead to deadlocks, no matter what. A stricter isolation level such as `SERIALIZABLE` will lead to deadlocks quicker than lenient isolation levels. `READ_COMMITTED` and `REPEATABLE_READ` will lead to less frequent deadlocks but may have challenges in specific scenarios. I have used `REPEATABLE_READ` for similar scenarios throughout my career without any noticeable problems. For example, we use a similar strategy for generating company-specific invoice serial numbers and have not seen any problems in years in operation.

Comment: So, since deadlock is unavoidable, what do you do in the scenarios where you do get deadlocks? Simply retry? I'm just tweaking my algorithm now so deadlock are rare but not avoidable. If I do get a deadlock, I retry the transaction.

Comment: Yes, retry 6-40 times with random back-offs. I have usually seen operations completing within the first three tries but sometimes it may take longer under extreme concurrent loads.